# Can I create a somewhat complex Mechanical Turk HIT without much programming experience?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graph, mechanicalturk

I have a task that seems well-suited to Mturk. I've never before used the service, however, and despite reading through some of the documentation I'm having a difficult time judging how hard it would be to set up a task. I'm a strong beginner or weak intermediate in R. I've messed around with a project that involved a little understanding of XML. Otherwise, I have no programming or web development skills (I'm a statistician/epidemiologist). I'm hoping someone can give me an idea of what would be involved in creating my task so I can decide of it is worth the effort to learn how to create a HIT.

Essentially, I have recurring projects that require many graphs to be digitized (i.e. go from images to x,y coordinates). The automatic digitization software that I've tried isn't great for this task because some of the graphs are from old journal articles and they have gray-scale lines that cross each other multiple times. Figuring out which line is which requires a little human judgement. Workflow for the HIT would be to have each Mturker:

- Download a properly named empty Excel workbook.
- Download a JPEG of the graphs.
- Download a free plot digitization program.
- Open the graph in the plot digitization software, calibrate the axes, trace the outline of each curve, paste the coordinates into the corresponding Excel workbook that I have given them, extract some numbers off the graph into a second sheet of the same workbook.
- Send me the Excel files.

I'd have these done in duplicate to make sure that there is acceptable agreement between the two Mturkers who did each graph.

Is this a reasonable task to accomplish via Mechanical Turk? If so, can a somewhat intelligent person who isn't a programmer/web developer pull it off? I've poked around the internet a bit but I still can't tell if I just haven't found the right resource to teach me how to do this or if I'd need 5 years of experience as a web developer to pull it off. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No this really isn't a task for Mechanical Turk at all. Not only because you are requiring them to download a bunch of stuff which they won't do, but it's way too complex for them to have confidence they are doing it right and will get paid. Pay is binary so could go through all that for nothing.

You are also probably violating terms of service if they have to divulge personal info for the programs.

If you have a continuous need for this then MAYBE you can prequalify people by creating qualification on the service and then using just those workers.